# `snap list --all` does not show everyting in /var/lib/snapd/snaps

Tags: linux, ubuntu, snap

I have lots of old snaps in `/var/libd/snaps`

```
#> ls /var/lib/snapd/snaps | sort
bare_5.snap
chromium_2556.snap
chromium_2642.snap
core_16091.snap
core18_2790.snap
core20_2015.snap
core22_864.snap
cups_980.snap
firefox_2579.snap
firefox_2645.snap
firefox_2667.snap
firefox_2710.snap
firefox_2760.snap
firefox_2800.snap
firefox_3026.snap
firefox_3131.snap
firefox_3166.snap
firefox_3206.snap
geth_477.snap
gnome-3-28-1804_198.snap
gnome-3-34-1804_93.snap
gnome-3-38-2004_143.snap
gnome-42-2204_141.snap
gtk-common-themes_1535.snap
hunspell-dictionaries-1-7-2004_2.snap
musescore_228.snap
partial
pycharm-community_347.snap
snapd_20092.snap
snap-store_959.snap
spotify_68.snap
```

But

```
#> snap list --all
Name                            Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher      Notes
bare                            1.0                         5      latest/stable    canonical✓     base
chromium                        117.0.5938.92               2642   latest/stable    canonical✓     -
core                            16-2.60.3                   16091  latest/stable    canonical✓     core
core18                          20230703                    2790   latest/stable    canonical✓     base
core20                          20230801                    2015   latest/stable    canonical✓     base
core22                          20230801                    864    latest/stable    canonical✓     base
cups                            2.4.6-4                     980    latest/stable    openprinting✓  -
firefox                         118.0.1-1                   3206   latest/stable    mozilla✓       -
geth                            v1.9.5                      477    latest/stable    elopio         -
gnome-3-28-1804                 3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  198    latest/stable    canonical✓     -
gnome-3-34-1804                 0+git.3556cb3               93     latest/stable/…  canonical✓     -
gnome-3-38-2004                 0+git.efb213a               143    latest/stable    canonical✓     -
gnome-42-2204                   0+git.ff35a85               141    latest/stable    canonical✓     -
gtk-common-themes               0.1-81-g442e511             1535   latest/stable/…  canonical✓     -
hunspell-dictionaries-1-7-2004  1.7-20.04+pkg-6fd6          2      latest/stable    brlin          -
musescore                       3.6.2                       228    latest/stable    musescore✓     -
pycharm-community               2023.2.2                    347    latest/stable    jetbrains✓     classic
snap-store                      41.3-71-g709398e            959    latest/stable/…  canonical✓     -
snapd                           2.60.3                      20092  latest/stable    canonical✓     snapd
spotify                         1.2.13.661.ga588f749        68     latest/stable    spotify✓       -
```

does not show all of these.

I have elsewhere seen a script to clean old snaps

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 snap list --all | awk '/disabled/{print $1, $3}' |
    while read snapname revision; do
        sudo snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$revision"
    done
```

this works on some old snaps but leaves some in place.

Are the entries in `/var/libd/snaps` somehow broken, that they are not seen by `snap --list`? What should I do, just delete them?

Comment: My own choice was to remove SNAP entirely and to download from PPA's. For example, you list 10 instances of Firefox, each containing *all* dependencies, redundantly, an immense waste of space.

Comment: Hey, OP, did you find any solution?